# Problems with Path Distance tool in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cost-path

for the first time I run the Path Distance tool in ArcGIS but I guess something went wrong, and the process went into a loop.
I needed to calculate the path distance to rivers. I use a rivers shpfile (lines) and the DEM as surface raster.

Comment: are you using python or modelbuilder? I think you may need to input a cost raster (ei: reclasified slope, weighted overlay analysis etc..) not just a a surface raster. and what do you mean by loop?